# How to access/cast the module output to specific object in bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I am having below bicep which is returning keyvault. I like to access the properties/functions in keyvault in parent bicep. But not sure how to achieve when using it as a module.

1. I have **keyvault.bicep**

```
    resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
         name: kvName
         scope: resourceGroup(subscriptionId, kvResourceGroup )
       }
       output kv1 object=kv
```

2. I have **parent.bicep** (where keyvault.bicep is included as module)

```
   module kv './keyvault.bicep' = {
     name: 'get Secrets'
     params: {
       subscriptionId: subscriptionId
       kvResourceGroup: resourceGroupName
       kvName: keyVaultName
     }
   }
   var pwd= kv.outputs.kv1.getSecret('key')
```

3. but getSecret method is unknown in parent bicep

Kindly suggest how to proceed?

Comment: do you really need the key vault bicep file ? you could just reference key vault directly in the parent bicep file ?

Comment: How are you going to use this `pwd` variable in the rest of the template? The thing is that [getSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#use-getsecret-function) function has some special requirements on how it can be used.

Comment: @Thomas Here Keyvault is just an example.. It can be storage account or resource group..

Comment: @ochzhen I agree with you, that it cannot be assigned to the variable. It can only be assigned to a secure parameter to the module. As I was saying, the key vault is an example.  I understood from the below answer that this feature is currently unsupported in the bicep.

Comment: I am not sure why it is downvoted. Please comment why it is downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that is not supported.

> In your `parent.bicep` file, **kv** is a module reference, not a resource. In order to correctly understand the parent-child resource hierarchy, Bicep requires a resource reference of the correct parent type in the parent property value.

Tho there is a proposal to simplify resource referencing:

- https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/2246

Let say you have `keyvault.bicep` module that creates a key vault

```bicep
resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' = {
  name: kvName
  ...
}

output name string = kv.name
```

In the parent.bicep, you could get a reference to key vault like that:

```bicep
module kvModule './keyvault.bicep' = {
  name: 'key-vault-${keyVaultName}'
  params: {
    kvName: keyVaultName
    ...
  }
}

resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: kvModule.outputs.name
}
```

In you example, there are few things:

- The key vault module just gets a reference to key vault so you don't really  need a module, you could just reference the key vault directly in the parent.bicep file.
- The [getSecret function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource#getsecret) is a really specific function, you can only use it to pass secure parameter to another module:

  > Returns a secret from an Azure Key Vault. The `getSecret` function can only be called on a `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults` resource. Use this function to pass a secret to a secure string parameter of a Bicep module. The function can be used only with a parameter that has the `@secure()` decorator.

Comment: Thank you... So means `getSecret` function cannot be used if the resource is present in `parent bicep`... it can only be passed as a secure param to the module. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: This will not work:
resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: kvModule..outputs.name
}

This expression is being used in an assignment to the "name" property of the "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults" type, which requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the deployment. Properties of keyVaultModule which can be calculated at the start include "name".bicep(BCP120)

Comment: @MarkusMeyer could you please elaborate ? not sure if it is related

Comment: @sub, the secret must exist before the deployment starts. You could wrap it in it s own module to make it work